# Where can I find scans of D&D:TFBG board game cards?

Tags: components

My friend has bought second hand [Dungeons and Dragons The Fantasy Board Game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6366/dungeons-dragons-the-fantasy-adventure-board-game) and about half of the cards is missing. He'd like to print the missing cards himself to be able to play the game.

Are the scans of the cards available anywhere for download and print?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you can find scans to download and print, but you can use BGG to help out with things:

- [Full component list (with card names, but not full card text)](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/30526/dungeons-and-dragons-board-game-comprehensive-comp)
- [2013 Spare Parts Resource List entry for the game](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/150255/item/2408611#item2408611) - He could post his wants there after seeing what is missing
- [Image gallery for the game](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/images/boardgame/6366/dungeons-dragons-the-fantasy-adventure-board-game) (15 pages of images, there might be images of the cards)

Not a lot of scanning of cards for printing purposes because that leads to copyright issues, and since we're talking about WotC, they WILL go after people with C&D orders if and when they find that sort of thing. But the above links should help him in getting the actual cards.